# R Question: Extracting Numeric Characters from End of String

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame. One of the columns is in string format. Various letters and numbers, but always ending in a string of numbers. Sadly this string isn't always the same length.

I'd like to know how to write a bit of code to extract just the numbers at the end. So for example:

```
x <- c("AB ABC 19012301927 / XX - 4625",
       "BC - AB / 827 / 9765",
       "XXXX-9276"
)
```

And I'd like to get from this: (4625, 9765, 9276)

Is there any easy way to do this please?

Thank you.
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string that follows a non-digit (`[^0-9]`) and other characters (`.*`), in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*[^0-9](\\d+)$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "4625" "9765" "9276"
```

---

Or with `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(x, -1, sep="[- ]")
#[1] "4625" "9765" "9276"
```

---

Or with `stri_extract_last`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d+")
#[1] "4625" "9765" "9276"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I should have said: I need to keep leading zeroes in the output so I guess I should keep it as a string instead of a numeric. But that simplifies things because I can just remove the as.numeric() call and keep the sub(".*[^0-9](\\d+)$", "\\1", x) part - it seems to work nicely

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything up to the last non-digit with a zero length string.

```
sub(".*\\D", "", x)
```

giving:

```
[1] "4625" "9765" "9276"
```